# How to see an XML code in its PDF format?

Tags: xml, pdf, metadata

Hello friends I have a problem when I see this address, it turns out that I am passionate about old texts, so I started to research about archimedes and a lost book about it, but the data where they are stored, are in strange formats (little common that I do not know), and there are several texts that I would like to read but I do not allow, I get the source code, but not the text itself, I would like someone to help me solve this problem to continue my research on the recently discovered books of archimedes.

The data is in this address:

(http://archimedespalimpsest.net/Supplemental/ArchimedesTranscriptions/Method/)

and the file that I want to read is in this address that is in an XML extension.

(http://archimedespalimpsest.net/Supplemental/ArchimedesTranscriptions/Method/Method-NW-p5.xml)

This is what I get when I enter this page

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

postscript: it would be excellent if it could be converted into pdf format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be encoded by the [Text Encoding Initiative](http://www.tei-c.org/index.xml). Who conveniently have a tool for converting them to whatever format you want.

http://www.tei-c.org/oxgarage/#

To convert the provided link I set the input to Documents > 
TEI P5 XML Document